# best way to embed LIGHTWEIGHT GWT 'widgets' into websites

Tags: gwt

I know this is similar to other topics, but I've not yet found a satisfactory answer.

I have a GWT / GAEJ application that essentially allows users to interact with the web app as if it were a desktop app.  i.e. they login, and use the application in full-html mode (i.e. the GWT app occupies the entire html page).  They are typically power users and so don't mind a few seconds dowload / login time when starting to use the app.  Typically they might stay logged in for several hours.

I would also like to make available some small subsets of functionality, pointing to the same Back end, as widgets to be included in OTHER existing websites.  I know one of the features of GWT is that you can either embed your GWT into existing html pages or go full page.

My question is how do I partition the GWT components into small tidy parcels so that only the relevant bits are downloaded for these embedded 'widgets' whist not having to duplicate my backend code.  (for example I could create a new GWT project write only my small widget and copy the server side code - but I really don't want to do this!)  Each widget still needs to interact with the same backend so none of them will be stand alone GWT.  Communication is GWT-RPC.

anyone done this?

Comment: It also depends on how you communicate with the backend (Requestfactory, GWT-RPC, JSON/XML parsing)? Can you update your question and explain how client-backend communication is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to split your GWT stuff into multiple GWT modules that you want to later combine in possibly more than one project. One way is having a [multi-module](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/project.html#Multi-project_setup) maven setup (gwt-maven-plugin), there's no need to copy/paste code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  No I haven't tried that yet, because from what I can see its not what its what I'm after.  Unless I'm mistaken that just lets you incrementally load parts of the SAME client as you need them, rather than my requirement.  I need to send distinct client snippets to certain websites each talking to same backend.  However I will revisit the code-splitting docs to see if I've missed something.

Comment: ok, that sounds more interesting.  Not using Maven yet, but I will investigate.  My concern is not wanting to duplicate any code, and yet being able to include all my GWT mini-apps for when I deploy my app.  So this sounds promising, thanks.  Do you have any experience of doing this?

Comment: you don't need maven, it's also doable with ant (and remember to export the sources). i've been doing this for few years now, works just fine.

Comment: thanks for that milan, I'll investigate.  Currently I'm just building in Eclipse with the plugin, so I don't even have any ant scripts, its all very nicely done by google.  However down side is it shields you from all the build script details.  I guess I create a new project for my new GWT app (but somehow link it to my existing project to communicate with the backend)??

Comment: it should also be possible with eclipse, if you configure project dependencies and to export sources (remember, GWT needs *.java for all the code you use on the client side). If that's what you mean by "linking".